# Vue Grid Layout Usage in Vue3 new project

Tags: vuejs3

I'm new to vue3.

I installed the Vue Grid Layout package, and then created a component exactly as their example.

im getting: "Failed to resolve import "vue-grid-layout" from "src\components\Dashboard.vue". Does the file exist?"

Should i register it in main.js by app.use? is it mendatory?

````
<template>
    <grid-layout :layout.sync="layout"
                 :col-num="12"
                 :row-height="30"
                 :is-draggable="draggable"
                 :is-resizable="resizable"
                 :vertical-compact="true"
                 :use-css-transforms="true"
    >
        <grid-item v-for="item in layout"
                   :static="item.static"
                   :x="item.x"
                   :y="item.y"
                   :w="item.w"
                   :h="item.h"
                   :i="item.i"
        >
            <span class="text">{{itemTitle(item)}}</span>
        </grid-item>
    </grid-layout>
</template>

<script>
import { GridLayout, GridItem } from "vue-grid-layout"

export default {
    components: {
        GridLayout,
        GridItem
    },
    data() {
        return {
            layout: [
                {"x":0,"y":0,"w":2,"h":2,"i":"0", static: false},
                {"x":2,"y":0,"w":2,"h":4,"i":"1", static: true},
                {"x":4,"y":0,"w":2,"h":5,"i":"2", static: false}
            ],
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true,
            index: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        itemTitle(item) {
            let result = item.i;
            if (item.static) {
                result += " - Static";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.vue-grid-layout {
    background: #eee;
}

.vue-grid-item:not(.vue-grid-placeholder) {
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
...etc...etc...
</style>```
````

Comment: The github for this library seems to imply it only supports Vue 2.  There is an unpublished vue 3 branch in beta, and some forked vue 3 versions as well.  See [this github thread](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout/issues/439)

Answer (score 0):

This one is working as expected:
https://grid-layout-plus.netlify.app/